# How do I count & get the name of category after grouping column in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have table with 3 columns

```
user_id
category
view_hour
```

I made a query for selecting `user_id` that watched only one`category` (Drama or Variety or pop).

Here is my query :

```
select *    
    from (
        select user_id, category, sum(view_hour)
        from kcp_01
        group by user_id, category) p
group by p.user_id

having count(*) = 1)
```

But, I want to get the number of user and the category who watched only one category.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the users who watched only one category using:

```
select user_id, min(category) as category, sum(view_hour)
from kcp_01
group by user_id
having min(category) = max(category);
```

Note that `min(category)` is *the* category, because there is only one category.

In Hive, you may need to do:

```
select user_id, min(category) as min_category,
       max(category) as max_category, sum(view_hour)
from kcp_01
group by user_id
having min_category = max_category;
```

If you want the number of such users per category, then a subquery is helpful:

```
select category, count(*) as number_single_users
from (select user_id, min(category) as min_category, max(category) as max_category, sum(view_hour) as view_hours
      from kcp_01
      group by user_id
      having min_category) = max_category
    ) u
group by category;
```

An alternative method would simply use `not exists`:

```
select k.category, count(distinct k.user_id)
from kcp_01 k
where not exists (select 1
                  from kcp_01 k2
                  where k2.user_id = k.user_id and
                        k2.category <> k.category
                 )
group by k.category;
```

I recall -- once upon a time -- that Hive has difficulty with `count(distinct)`, so the two-`group by` method may work better.

Comment: When I excute the query, i keep get this message.

Your query has the following error(s):

OK FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 4:23 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'max'

Comment: @문태욱 . . . Hive has something weird about not accepting aggregation functions in the `having` clause.  You need to actually select the columns and use the aliases.

Comment: You are god!!
I really love you~~~
Thank you veryveryvery much!!:D